# how to display a canvas on a wpf custom control library?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I have a wpf custom control which draws stuff on a canvas. but i cant figure out how to display this canvas on the window. When i add this control to a host app, I want this canvas to fill that app's window. I have seen some tutorial which use template binding to display ui elements etc but i read that canvas doesnt have a template property or something... How can display this canvas that I am drawing on? thanks

```
 namespace WPFCustomControls { 

       public class MyCustomControl : Control { 
           private Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

          static MyCustomControl() { 
             DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl), new
                FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl))); 
          } 

             public void drawOnCanvas()
              {
                 //draw stuff on canvas
              }
               public void displayCanvas()
              {
                 //display canvas on app window
              }

       } 
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you simply derive from Canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deriving from `Control`, you could derive from [`ContentControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which has a [`Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.105).aspx) property.

For example:

```
public class MyCustomControl : ContentControl 
{ 
    private Canvas _canvas = new Canvas();

    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        this.Content = _canvas;
    }
}
```

---

It's also possible to derive from `Canvas` directly.